# Git Bare configuration for multiple projects

Tags: git, dvcs

We are trying to maintain a centralised repo for all of our projects (We are using windows server)

- E:\Repo

  - Project 1
  - Project 2
  - Project 3
  - Project 4

now I want to share the repo details with my fellow developers but I would like to do it with sort of credentials like team working on project 1 shouldn't able to pull/push into project 2.

How can we achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: there is any reason why you don't want to have one repo per project?

Comment: Project1.git and projectx.git are different bare repos...Am doing it in any wrong way ?

Comment: @user1042031 - You should probably look into [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki) which allows creating users and groups. You could control which users/groups have what kind of permissions on a per-repo basis.

Comment: Is it available for windows ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the [Bonobo Git Server](http://www.chodounsky.net/bonobo-git-server/), and possibly [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/).  It looks like there's a [setup guide using Tomcat and LDAP for Gerrit](https://serverfault.com/questions/383573/how-do-i-install-gerrit-under-tomcat-with-ldap) over on serverfault.com.

Unfortunately, I've not used either one of them, so I can't speak for their performance.  I do know that Gerrit is used to manage the Android repositories though.